# How to make my Facebook ID with one word only?

Tags: facebook

My Facebook name is **Raihan Khalil**. But I want to make it just **Raihan**. I tried but can't do it. Facebook requires you to have a first and last name. I've seen some people on Facebook with just a single name, how can I do that?

Comment: You want to change your Username, then (the one that you see in the URL `www.facebook.com/Username`)?

Comment: In Indonesia, some people just have a single name, so Facebook allows people in that country to use a single name. You can trick Facebook into thinking you live in Indonesia by using a web proxy based in that country, then try changing your Facebook name to a single name, and it should work. Full instructions on how to do it are here: 
http://www.safetricks.com/2012/10/Make-Facebook-Account-With-Single-Name.html

Comment: @macknordstrum I have reopened if you want to add that as an answer. I don't know if that procedure still works, though.

Comment: That blog is a bit spammy as well.  I'll see how the community feels about it.

Comment: @macknordstrum I have a FB friend in America who just has her first name on her profile, and I doubt she's savvy enough to use a web proxy in Indonesia.  Wonder if there's some other way she changed it?

Comment: using the web proxy is a one off event for setting your name, you dont have to continuously use it whenever you browse facebook. its simple enough to follow the instructions in the guide, anyone could do it. there are probably simpler guides out there. im pretty sure this is the only way to get a single name id on fb.

Answer (score 1):

In Indonesia, Facebook allows people to keep their name limited to one word because Indonesia has a mononymic (single name) system. For more info see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_names#Mononymic_names.

Most Indonesians don't have surnames (family names) so Facebook allows people in that country to use a single name. You can trick Facebook into thinking you live in Indonesia by using a web proxy based in that country, then try changing your Facebook name to a single name, and it should work ok. Full instructions on how to do it are here: http://www.safetricks.com/2012/10/Make-Facebook-Account-With-Single-Name.html